# basic jquery slider image sizes not resizable

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, image-gallery

I have a basic jquery slider that i have made resizable.

the container resizes but the inner images do not.

I have created a jsfiddle to show this. http://jsfiddle.net/B9nVy/48/

in this bit of code on my site

```
$('#banner').bjqs({
    'animation': 'slide',
    'width': 700,
    'height': 300,
```

if I set height and width to 100% then the images resize, but the slider stops working

If I set the height and width to a number say height:700 width:300 then the container will only resize keeping the scale, so the user cannot change the ratio to say 300x300 and the max height and width stays at the set height and width

does anyone know how I can over come this

code

css:

```
    ul.bjqs {
         position:relative;
         list-style:none;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         overflow:hidden;
         display:none;
    }
    li.bjqs-slide {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
    }
    ul.bjqs-controls {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:9999;
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:9999;
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers li {
        float:left;
    }
    p.bjqs-caption {
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        margin:0;
        padding:2%;
        position:relative;
        bottom:0;
    }
    /* demo styles */

    #banner {
        height:300px;
        width:700px;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        background:#fff;
        border:2px #000 solid;

    }
    ul.bjqs-controls li a {
        display:block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        position:absolute;
        background:#fff;
        color:#fd0100;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    li.bjqs-slide div {
        background-color:#EEE;
        border:2px solid #000;
        height:200px;
    }
    a.bjqs-prev {
        left:0;
    }
    a.bjqs-next {
        right:0;
    }
    p.bjqs-caption {
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-50px;
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers li {
        float:left;
        margin:0 3px;
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers li a {
        display:block;
        height:10px;
        width:10px;
        border:4px solid #fff;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        background:#000;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a {
        background:#fd0100;
    }
```

js:

```
    $('#banner').bjqs({
        'animation': 'slide',
            'width': 700,
            'height': 300,
            'automatic': true,
            'animspeed': '3000',
            'showControls': true,
            'centerControls': true,
            'centerMarkers': false,
            'useCaptions': true

    });
    $(function () {
        $("#banner").resizable();
    });
```

html:

```
        <div id="banner">
        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
            <li>
                <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_irPxcWyLEmo/TP8k1GUp3LI/AAAAAAAAAD0/wIGvKoqhb-M/s320/African_Lion_King.jpg" title="lion" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/27c8612a25c299f98004c15b155cefad/ogbqjed/k2Bmmp0ut/tumblr_static_giraffes_wallpapers_156.jpg" title="giraffe" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://embc.gov.bc.ca/em/hazard_preparedness/wildlife_info_page_photo-05-large.jpg" title="bear" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->
    </div>
    <!-- End outer wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply height to `img` tag inside `li`, this will stretch height of image to fit container, and to center image by adding `text-align:center` rule to its container:

```
ul.bjqs img {
    height:100%;    
}

ul.bjqs {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DzFaP/

Depending on how you need to fit image you may want to stretch image by width instead of height:

```
ul.bjqs img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/fhbb4/

Comment: I added this to the jsfiddle with both height and width set to 100%, which makes the image fit the original container fine, but when I resize, the images do not resize, just the container resizes http://jsfiddle.net/B9nVy/51/

Comment: bjqs seems to rely only on absolute dimension of container (it animates `left` property of `ul` according to initial size of container) so you will have to recreate it on resizing `#banner` container.